# Chrome element inspector font size has become massive and unusable

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04, google-chrome-devtools

The font size of the element inspector has changed to a massive and therefore unusable size. The screenshot shows what it looked like on my 1920x1080px widescreen monitor! https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/21432350/Screenshot%20from%202013-09-25%2008%3A33%3A56.png

Probably I accidentally hit some key combination to cause this, but I can't figure out what it is. I've tried resetting the broswer settings and even re-installing Chrome, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: hit CTRL+0 (zero) in the inspector, you probably accidently increased the zoom using CTRL+PLUS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL+0 should set it back to the default.

Answer (score 0):

You many need to zoom out.

ctrl+minus or ctrl+scroll for windows
cmd+minus for macs